# Быстрый поиск члена рекуррентного соотношения схожего с числами Фибоначчи

Tags: алгоритм, числа-фибоначчи

Fn = Fn-3 + Fn-1.
F0 = 0, F1 = 1, F2 = 1.
Можно ли модифицировать матрический способ поиска числа Фибоначчи для решения этой проблемы? Если нет, то возможен ли поиск члена быстрее O(n)?

Comment: Что есть "матрический"? Ответ: можно все что угодно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Для таких рекуррентных соотношений обычно можно формулу вывести. И будет константное время. Только точность так себе. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: @AlexeyTen Для этого соотношения надо кубические уравнения решать, если не ошибаюсь.

Answer (score 4):

Ну давайте покумекаем. Имеется три члена ряда, нужно получить три следующих (с номерами на единицу больше)

```
                     [a  b  c] 
[Fn-3  Fn-2  Fn-1] x [d  e  f] = [Fn-2  Fn-1  Fn]
                     [g  h  i]
```

Первый столбец матрицы перемножается со вектором слева и должен дать первый элемент вектора-результата Fn-2 из соотношения

```
Fn-2 = a * Fn-3 + d * Fn-2 + g * Fn-1
```

так что a=0, d=1, g=0
Второй столбец матрицы перемножается со вектором слева и должен дать Fn-1
Третий столбец матрицы перемножается со вектором слева и должен дать Fn
Получается

```
            [0  0  1] ^(n-2) 
[0  1  1] x [1  0  0]        =  [Fn-2  Fn-1  Fn]
            [0  1  1]
```

Попробуйте проверить

Я проверил, для 43 степени даёт [8407925](http://oeis.org/A078012/list)

Comment: @Юхим Федорович Ответ непонятен?